Issue with Future-Dated Commit Preventing AWS Amplify Auto-Deploy
I have encountered an issue with our GitHub repository that is affecting our AWS Amplify auto-deploy process. A commit was mistakenly made with a future date and has been merged into the dev branch and pushed to the remote repository. As a result, AWS Amplify is treating subsequent commits with correct dates as older, preventing them from triggering automatic deployments.
Steps to reproduce:
1.Create a commit with a future date.
2.Merge this commit into the dev branch.
3.Push the dev branch to the remote repository.
4.Observe that subsequent commits with correct dates do not trigger AWS Amplify auto-deploy.
To resolve this, I need to amend the commit date of the affected commit to the correct date and push the updated history to the remote repository. However, this will require force-pushing changes to the dev branch, which might affect other team members.
Could you please advise on the best approach to correct this issue and ensure that AWS Amplify can resume automatic deployments?
Thank you for your assistance.
amend the commit date of the affected commit to the correct date and push the updated history to the remote repository.
